# Make a text based game into an executable jar - Java

Tags: java, text

I was just wondering how one would go about making a text-based, console game into an executable jar.

From what I've seen on the rest of this website, I would need to use JTextField and JTextPane. I also know that to make it runnable it would need to create its own console. I do not care how complicated it is, so long as it is simple enough to understand. If this would be way, way to advanced could you please point me in the right direction to learning how to accomplish this.

*If this is a duplicate of a question somewhere else, please just point me in the direction; I've searched and cannot find any questions that are simple.*

Comment: An executable Jar will not show a console, and therefore not be suited to a console based game!  If you want to keep it console based, do without an executable Jar.  If you want an executable Jar, turn the app into one with a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the console, you can either run it from command line or like you said, make a GUI and have it act like a console.

The GUI can be done in two ways:

1. Create a simple GUI with a text box for output and 1 line for input. Add methods to write and get lines (respectively)
2. Create another simple GUI and a class that extends PrintStream. Override the write methods of the PrintStream class to have them write to the JTextPane you created. Follow the same format for InputStream (System.in). You can set these via System.setIn(InputStream) and System.setOut(PrintStream). The result of this method is more complicated but nonetheless gives a more complete feel.

More on #2:
@Jordan.McBride Everything in the System class is defined by the JRE. Before your program runs, the JRE will prepare all of the elements of the System class that your program might call. In doing so, it creates a PrintStream object and tells it to write to the console. Your program can call this class by using System.out. Similarly, the JRE also creates a InputStream object and assigns it to the console window, which you can reference via System.in. Java gives you the option to swap out these Stream classes with your own, via System.setIn(..) and System.setOut(..). This is useful in case that your program GUI fails that you don't have to show a user-unfriendly console to display an error.

By creating your own classes that override the PrintStream and InputStream classes, you can redirect where you want data to flow. Take a look at the API for the PrintStream class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). the println() and print() methods both call the write() functions. For the sake of simplicity, I would only override the print and println. In your overrided functions, you could have something as simple as

```
public void println(String outstr)
{
  this.textBox.setText(this.textBox.getText() + outStr + "\n");
}
```

You would of course have to have an instance field of textBox so that it knows where to write.

Comment: if possible, could you go more in-depth into option 2.? Just so I can get a bit more of an understanding as I have never done that before and I would like to know how to;

Comment: @Jordan.McBride I've edited in more info as it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: *"I've edited in more info"*  I actually think what you did is best, along with the comment 'see edit to answer'.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You need `JTextField` and `JTextPane` only if you want a GUI for your game.

For a console game,

First create a `manifest.txt`. Make sure to end in a new line.

```
Main-Class: MyMainClass
```

Then

```
javac MyMainClass.java SomeOtherClass.java
jar -cvfm my-game.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

Then to run it,

```
java -jar my-game.jar
```

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, i didn't read your answer correctly. I have a question, after creating a manifest.txt file, which .java files do I type into Terminal?

Comment: @Jordan.McBride, you type the .java files that your game will need. Obviously, if your game has non-trivial complexity, this becomes tedious. If you are using an IDE, it should be able to do all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easy solution, you could look into using the ACM Java Task Force library and subclassing ConsoleProgram. This should leave most of your current code intact.

http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/

Comment: Im not looking for an easy solution, but something that I could read for the first time and make heads or tail of it